# Zoom image from its touch coordinates not from center

Tags: android, coordinates, zooming, pinchzoom

this is my code i m successfully zooming from center but i want to zoom in from the touch coordinates like instagram image zoom.I tried this code till now.Help me through it please.

**ZoomImageActivity.java**

```
public class ZoomImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView ivBG;
private ZoomImageHelper imageZoomHelper;
private View zoomableView = null;
View.OnTouchListener zoomTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2 && zoomableView == null)
                    zoomableView = view;

                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom_image);

    ivBG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBG);
    ivBG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    ivBG.setOnTouchListener(zoomTouchListener);

    imageZoomHelper = new ZoomImageHelper(this, tvParam);
    imageZoomHelper.addOnZoomListener(new ZoomImageHelper.OnZoomListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageZoomStarted(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onImageZoomEnded(View view) {
            zoomableView = null;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return imageZoomHelper.onDispatchTouchEvent(ev, zoomableView) || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}}
```

**ZoomImageHelper.java**

```
public class ZoomImageHelper {
private View zoomableView = null;
private ViewGroup parentOfZoomableView;
private ViewGroup.LayoutParams zoomableViewLP;
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams zoomableViewFrameLP;
private Dialog dialog;
private View placeholderView;
private int viewIndex;
private View darkView;
private double originalDistance;
private int[] twoPointCenter;
private int[] originalXY;

private WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakReference;

private boolean isAnimatingDismiss = false;

private List<OnZoomListener> zoomListeners = new ArrayList<>();

public ZoomImageHelper(Activity activity) {
    this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
}

public boolean onDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev, View view) {
    Activity activity;
    if ((activity = activityWeakReference.get()) == null)
        return false;

    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        if (zoomableView == null) {
            if (view != null) {
                zoomableView = view;

                // get view's original location relative to the window
                originalXY = new int[2];
                view.getLocationInWindow(originalXY);

                // this FrameLayout will be the zoomableView's temporary parent
                FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(view.getContext());

                // this view is to gradually darken the backdrop as user zooms
                darkView = new View(view.getContext());
                darkView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                darkView.setAlpha(0f);

                // adding darkening backdrop to the frameLayout
                frameLayout.addView(darkView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                // the Dialog that will hold the FrameLayout
                dialog = new Dialog(activity,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

                dialog.addContentView(frameLayout,
                        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                dialog.show();

                // get the parent of the zoomable view and get it's index and layout param
                parentOfZoomableView = (ViewGroup) zoomableView.getParent();
                viewIndex = parentOfZoomableView.indexOfChild(zoomableView);
                this.zoomableViewLP = zoomableView.getLayoutParams();

                // this is the new layout param for the zoomableView
                zoomableViewFrameLP = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
                zoomableViewFrameLP.leftMargin = originalXY[0];
                zoomableViewFrameLP.topMargin = originalXY[1];

                // this view will hold the zoomableView's position temporarily
                placeholderView = new View(activity);

                // setting placeholderView's background to zoomableView's drawingCache
                // this avoids flickering when adding/removing views
                zoomableView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                BitmapDrawable placeholderDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(
                        activity.getResources(),
                        Bitmap.createBitmap(zoomableView.getDrawingCache()));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    placeholderView.setBackground(placeholderDrawable);
                } else {
                    placeholderView.setBackgroundDrawable(placeholderDrawable);
                }

                // placeholderView takes the place of zoomableView temporarily
                parentOfZoomableView.addView(placeholderView, zoomableViewLP);

                // zoomableView has to be removed from parent view before being added to it's
                // new parent
                parentOfZoomableView.removeView(zoomableView);
                frameLayout.addView(zoomableView, zoomableViewFrameLP);

                // using a post to remove placeholder's drawing cache
                zoomableView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (dialog != null) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                                placeholderView.setBackground(null);
                            } else {
                                placeholderView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                            }

                            zoomableView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Pointer variables to store the original touch positions
                MotionEvent.PointerCoords pointerCoords1 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
                ev.getPointerCoords(0, pointerCoords1);

                MotionEvent.PointerCoords pointerCoords2 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
                ev.getPointerCoords(1, pointerCoords2);

                // storing distance between the two positions to be compared later on for
                // zooming
                originalDistance = (int) getDistance(pointerCoords1.x, pointerCoords2.x,
                        pointerCoords1.y, pointerCoords2.y);

                // storing center point of the two pointers to move the view according to the
                // touch position
                twoPointCenter = new int[]{
                        (int) ((pointerCoords2.x + pointerCoords1.x) / 2),
                        (int) ((pointerCoords2.y + pointerCoords1.y) / 2)
                };

                sendZoomEventToListeners(zoomableView, true);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            MotionEvent.PointerCoords pointerCoords1 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
            ev.getPointerCoords(0, pointerCoords1);

            MotionEvent.PointerCoords pointerCoords2 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
            ev.getPointerCoords(1, pointerCoords2);

            int[] newCenter = new int[]{
                    (int) ((pointerCoords2.x + pointerCoords1.x) / 2),
                    (int) ((pointerCoords2.y + pointerCoords1.y) / 2)
            };

            int currentDistance = (int) getDistance(pointerCoords1.x, pointerCoords2.x,
                    pointerCoords1.y, pointerCoords2.y);
            double pctIncrease = (currentDistance - originalDistance) / originalDistance;

            zoomableView.setScaleX((float) (1 + pctIncrease));
            zoomableView.setScaleY((float) (1 + pctIncrease));

            updateZoomableViewMargins(newCenter[0] - twoPointCenter[0] + originalXY[0],
                    newCenter[1] - twoPointCenter[1] + originalXY[1]);

            darkView.setAlpha((float) (pctIncrease / 8));

            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (zoomableView != null && !isAnimatingDismiss) {
            isAnimatingDismiss = true;
            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(activity.getResources()
                    .getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime));
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                float scaleYStart = zoomableView.getScaleY();
                float scaleXStart = zoomableView.getScaleX();
                int leftMarginStart = zoomableViewFrameLP.leftMargin;
                int topMarginStart = zoomableViewFrameLP.topMargin;
                float alphaStart = darkView.getAlpha();

                float scaleYEnd = 1f;
                float scaleXEnd = 1f;
                int leftMarginEnd = originalXY[0];
                int topMarginEnd = originalXY[1];
                float alphaEnd = 0f;

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                    if (animatedFraction < 1) {
                        zoomableView.setScaleX(((scaleXEnd - scaleXStart) * animatedFraction) +
                                scaleXStart);
                        zoomableView.setScaleY(((scaleYEnd - scaleYStart) * animatedFraction) +
                                scaleYStart);

                        updateZoomableViewMargins(
                                ((leftMarginEnd - leftMarginStart) * animatedFraction) +
                                        leftMarginStart,
                                ((topMarginEnd - topMarginStart) * animatedFraction) +
                                        topMarginStart);

                        darkView.setAlpha(((alphaEnd - alphaStart) * animatedFraction) +
                                alphaStart);
                    } else {
                        dismissDialogAndViews();
                    }
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void updateZoomableViewMargins(float left, float top) {
    if (zoomableView != null && zoomableViewFrameLP != null) {
        zoomableViewFrameLP.leftMargin = (int) left;
        zoomableViewFrameLP.topMargin = (int) top;
        zoomableView.setLayoutParams(zoomableViewFrameLP);
    }
}

/**
 * Dismiss dialog and set views to null for garbage collection
 */
private void dismissDialogAndViews() {
    sendZoomEventToListeners(zoomableView, false);

    if (zoomableView != null) {
        zoomableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        zoomableView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        BitmapDrawable placeholderDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(
                zoomableView.getResources(),
                Bitmap.createBitmap(zoomableView.getDrawingCache()));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            placeholderView.setBackground(placeholderDrawable);
        } else {
            placeholderView.setBackgroundDrawable(placeholderDrawable);
        }

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) zoomableView.getParent();
        parent.removeView(zoomableView);
        this.parentOfZoomableView.addView(zoomableView, viewIndex, zoomableViewLP);
        this.parentOfZoomableView.removeView(placeholderView);

        zoomableView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        zoomableView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dismissDialog();
            }
        });

        zoomableView = null;
    } else {
        dismissDialog();
    }

    isAnimatingDismiss = false;
}

public void addOnZoomListener(OnZoomListener onZoomListener) {
    zoomListeners.add(onZoomListener);
}

public void removeOnZoomListener(OnZoomListener onZoomListener) {
    zoomListeners.remove(onZoomListener);
}

private void sendZoomEventToListeners(View zoomableView, boolean zoom) {
    for (OnZoomListener onZoomListener : zoomListeners) {
        if (zoom)
            onZoomListener.onImageZoomStarted(zoomableView);
        else
            onZoomListener.onImageZoomEnded(zoomableView);
    }
}

private void dismissDialog() {
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }

    darkView = null;
    resetOriginalViewAfterZoom();
}

private void resetOriginalViewAfterZoom() {
    zoomableView.invalidate();
    zoomableView = null;
}

/**
 * Get distance between two points
 *
 * @param x1
 * @param x2
 * @param y1
 * @param y2
 * @return distance
 */
private double getDistance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}

public interface OnZoomListener {

    void onImageZoomStarted(View view);

    void onImageZoomEnded(View view);

}}
```

I need the image to zoom and pan from its touch coordinates not from center.. Thanks in advance.